# Distance matrix between characters within a string

Tags: algorithm, matrix, distance

[image]

Let's say there are 8 characters(a to h). 
I have a string `cdegh`, and the distance matrix is like the above.

What’s the name of distance algorithm?

Comment: why is the diagonal not 0? how is this matrix populated?

Comment: What makes you think this specific distance matrix has a general algorithm that someone decided to name? I'm inclined to say it has no name, given all the 8's with somewhat arbitrary placement.

Comment: I just thought there is specific algorithm like this.

Comment: Total number of characters is 8. AND a, b, f doesn’t exist in the sample string.

Comment: C and D has 1 distance, and D and C has -1 distance and so on. If I use only upper side of diagonal, I don’t have to fill in 8 to those positions.